# Почему не происходит редирект?

Tags: php, редирект, header

Хочу использовать `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` для того чтобы возвращает пользователя на ту страницу с которой он отправлял данные, но редирект не происходит, стоит на странице обработчика. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] - это не та страница, "с которой пользователь отправлял данные", а та, которая была запрошена у сервера в данный момент.

Comment: @Ипатьев А как получить страницу с которой были отправлены данные?

Comment: Передать вместе с запросом. Или обрабатывать запрос на той же странице